# document.addEventListener blocking highlight in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

I did a div that is moveable but unfortunetaly the function that let user move the div also block the highlight of the text in the text area behind.

I would like to keep the possibility to move the div and to highlight the text in textarea like I want.

Ps: I already tried to put the addEventListener on varMoveButtonNotesWindow but it's really ncomfortable to use it like that (we need to keep the cursor in the little box, and I dont want the box to be bigger it wouldn't look good).

Here's the code:

```js
var mousePosition;
var offset = [0,0];
var isDown = false;
var varMoveButtonNotesWindow = document.getElementById('moveButtonNotesWindow');
var varNotesWindow = document.getElementById('notesWindow');

varMoveButtonNotesWindow.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    isDown = true;
    offset = [
        varNotesWindow.offsetLeft - e.clientX,
        varNotesWindow.offsetTop - e.clientY
    ];
}, true);

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    isDown = false;
}, true);

//The bug occurs here
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
    if (isDown) {
        mousePosition = {
    
            x : event.clientX,
            y : event.clientY
    
        };
        varNotesWindow.style.left = (mousePosition.x + offset[0]) + 'px';
        varNotesWindow.style.top  = (mousePosition.y + offset[1]) + 'px';
    }
}, true); 
//so far


function closeNotesWindow() {
  varNotesWindow.classList.remove('show');
}

function openNotesWindow() {
  windowsModalContainer.classList.remove('show');
  varNotesWindow.classList.add('show');
};
```

```css
.firstTextarea {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

#notesWindow {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 275px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border: 2px solid #313131;
  z-index: 2;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

#headerNotesWindow {
  height: 35px;
  background-color: black;
}


#moveButtonNotesWindow {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  right: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 7.5px;
}

#closeButtonNotesWindow {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 7.5px;
}

#divTextareaNotesWindow {
  text-align: center;
  height: calc(100% - 6px - 35px);
}

#textareaNotesWindow {
  resize: none;
  width: calc(100% - 6px);
  height: 100%;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="firstTextarea">Pokemon is the best game of my childhood.</textarea>

<div class="divWindow" id="notesWindow">
    <div id="headerNotesWindow">
      <div id="moveButtonNotesWindow"></div>
      <div id="closeButtonNotesWindow" onclick="closeNotesWindow()"></div>
    </div>
  
    <div id="divTextareaNotesWindow">
      <textarea id="textareaNotesWindow"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You can’t: if you want to drag the element of course you can’t perform highlighting of the text inside. These two operations are mutually exclusive for a simple reason: if you move the element, the text moves—and highlighting isn’t possible. I’d suggest implementing a keyboard shortcut so that perhaps dragging can be enabled or disabled based on a mouse down + key combination, so that the user can select the test in within.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found it, i just created a div that replace document for the addeventListener.

Ps I set the color to rgba(0, 175, 0, 0.3) just for you to see how it react and work you can obviously change it to 0.

```js
function start() {
  varNotesWindow.classList.add('show');
}

var mousePosition;
var offset = [0,0];
var isDown = false;
var varMoveButtonNotesWindow = document.getElementById('moveButtonNotesWindow');
var varNotesWindow = document.getElementById('notesWindow');
const constAlternativeDocumentForMoveButtonsWindow = document.getElementById('alternativeDocumentForMoveButtonsWindowId');

//Start Move Notes Window
varMoveButtonNotesWindow.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    isDown = true;
    offset = [
        varNotesWindow.offsetLeft - e.clientX,
        varNotesWindow.offsetTop - e.clientY
    ];
    constAlternativeDocumentForMoveButtonsWindow.classList.add('use');
}, true);


constAlternativeDocumentForMoveButtonsWindow.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
    if (isDown) {
        mousePosition = {
    
            x : event.clientX,
            y : event.clientY
    
        };
        varNotesWindow.style.left = (mousePosition.x + offset[0]) + 'px';
        varNotesWindow.style.top  = (mousePosition.y + offset[1]) + 'px';
    }
}, true);

constAlternativeDocumentForMoveButtonsWindow.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  constAlternativeDocumentForMoveButtonsWindow.classList.remove('use');
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    isDown = false;
}, true);
//End Move Notes Window

function closeNotesWindow() {
  varNotesWindow.classList.remove('show');
}

function openNotesWindow() {
  windowsModalContainer.classList.remove('show');
  varNotesWindow.classList.add('show');
};
```

```css
.alternativeDocumentForMoveButtonsWindowClass {
  display: none;
}

.alternativeDocumentForMoveButtonsWindowClass.use {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 175, 0, 0.3);
}


#notesWindow {
  display: none;
}

#notesWindow.show {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 275px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border: 2px solid #313131;
  z-index: 2;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

#headerNotesWindow {
  height: 35px;
  background-color: black;
}


#moveButtonNotesWindow {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  right: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 7.5px;
}

#closeButtonNotesWindow {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 7.5px;
}

#divTextareaNotesWindow {
  text-align: center;
  height: calc(100% - 6px - 35px);
}

#textareaNotesWindow {
  resize: none;
  width: calc(100% - 6px);
  height: 100%;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick='start()'>Let's Go</div>

<div class="alternativeDocumentForMoveButtonsWindowClass" id="alternativeDocumentForMoveButtonsWindowId"></div>
  
  <div class="divWindow" id="notesWindow">
    <div id="headerNotesWindow">
      <div id="moveButtonNotesWindow"></div>
      <div id="closeButtonNotesWindow" onclick="closeNotesWindow()"></div>
    </div>
  
    <div id="divTextareaNotesWindow">
      <textarea id="textareaNotesWindow"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can do like but not perfact：

RollBack selection when focus back it.

```js
var mousePosition;
var offset = [0,0];
var isDown = false;
var varMoveButtonNotesWindow = document.getElementById('moveButtonNotesWindow');
var varNotesWindow = document.getElementById('notesWindow');

varMoveButtonNotesWindow.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  isDown = true;
  offset = [
    varNotesWindow.offsetLeft - e.clientX,
    varNotesWindow.offsetTop - e.clientY
  ];
}, true);

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  isDown = false;
}, true);

//The bug occurs here
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) { 
  event.preventDefault();
  if (isDown) {
    mousePosition = {

      x : event.clientX,
      y : event.clientY

    };
    varNotesWindow.style.left = (mousePosition.x + offset[0]) + 'px';
    varNotesWindow.style.top  = (mousePosition.y + offset[1]) + 'px';
  }
}, true); 
//so far

window.addEventListener('load',function(){
  var logTextSelection = function(event) {
    var tgItem = event.target;
    tgItem.setAttribute("lastSelectionStart",tgItem.selectionStart);
    tgItem.setAttribute("lastSelectionEnd",tgItem.selectionEnd);
  }
  var rollBackSelection = function(event){
    var tgItem = event.target;
    var lastSelectionStart = tgItem.getAttribute("lastSelectionStart");
    var lastSelectionEnd = tgItem.getAttribute("lastSelectionEnd");
    if((lastSelectionStart !== lastSelectionEnd)){
      tgItem.focus();
      tgItem.setSelectionRange(lastSelectionStart,lastSelectionEnd);
    }
  }
  var docTextareas = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
  for (var i = 0; i < docTextareas.length; i++) {
    docTextareas[i].addEventListener('select', logTextSelection, true);
    docTextareas[i].addEventListener('keyup', logTextSelection, true);
    docTextareas[i].addEventListener('focus', rollBackSelection, true);
  }
});


function closeNotesWindow() {
  varNotesWindow.classList.remove('show');
}

function openNotesWindow() {
  windowsModalContainer.classList.remove('show');
  varNotesWindow.classList.add('show');
};
```

```css
.firstTextarea {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

#notesWindow {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 275px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border: 2px solid #313131;
  z-index: 2;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

#headerNotesWindow {
  height: 35px;
  background-color: black;
}


#moveButtonNotesWindow {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  right: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 7.5px;
}

#closeButtonNotesWindow {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 7.5px;
}

#divTextareaNotesWindow {
  text-align: center;
  height: calc(100% - 6px - 35px);
}

#textareaNotesWindow {
  resize: none;
  width: calc(100% - 6px);
  height: 100%;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="firstTextarea">Pokemon is the best game of my childhood.</textarea>

<div class="divWindow" id="notesWindow">
    <div id="headerNotesWindow">
      <div id="moveButtonNotesWindow"></div>
      <div id="closeButtonNotesWindow" onclick="closeNotesWindow()"></div>
    </div>
  
    <div id="divTextareaNotesWindow">
      <textarea id="textareaNotesWindow"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
```